# WIX best practices questions

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

Should the single component below be split into two components?

```
<Component Id="cmpSoftwareDLL" Guid="8401EA84-0A93-43A5-83D0-472B63418F92" Win64="$(var.MyWin64)">
<File Id="SoftwareDLL" Source="$(var.Software.TargetDir)\..\Release Obfuscated\Software.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
<Class Id="{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Software"
    ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
    <ProgId Id="$(var.ProgId)" Description="Software" />
</Class>

<!--Writes to Registry-->
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Class" Value="Software.Addin" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Assembly" Value="Software, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#SoftwareDLL]" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32" Name="Class" Value="Software.Addin" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32" Name="Assembly" Value="Software, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{2593B03A-8833-43EC-8F4F-A71E35CB58E6}\InprocServer32" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#SoftwareDLL]" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

Should I include KeyPath="yes" to one of these registry settings? What is the consequence of forgetting to including the KeyPath="yes" on any of them in an MSI file that is deployed? Can they be removed if a Windows Upgrade Path happens or similar?

```
<Component Id="cmpCustomerRegistry" Guid="BD933C43-A40A-4DBA-8645-F5E80F9134F1" Win64="$(var.MyWin64)">
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Policies\MySoftware">
    <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Name1" Value =0 />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Name2" Value ="value" />
    ....
</RegistryKey>
```

Answer (score 3):

The typical core questions to answer when deciding whether to combine or split component contents are:

- Are these parts meaningful without those parts?
- Will these parts need to be upgraded separately from those parts?
- Are there other guidelines suggesting to split or combine these parts?

  - [Defining Installer Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368269.aspx)
  - [Organize the installation of your application around components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770.aspx#organize_components)

For example, guidelines tell us to separate each PE file, so each .dll or .exe should receive its own component, even though the .exe may be useless without all of its .dll dependencies. By contrast, external .config or .manifest files do not stand on their own, so should in a single component with their corresponding .dll or .exe file.

I would argue that the registry data for your COM Server is meaningless without the COM Server itself. Short of a bug in your installer contents, you will never need to upgrade your registry data without also upgrading the .dll file. And there's no guidance to the contrary. So, unless you have unusual needs (like to be able to install the COM Server without its registration), keep your .dll and its registration in a single component.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Seems to make sense.